# How to list all installed and uninstalled optional Windows components on command line?

Tags: windows, command-line

Optional components in Windows are, for example, IIS, telnet server/client, SNMP, etc. In Windows 7 GUI they are installed through Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off.

On command line you can install them using `ocsetup` utility, but you have to know the component name for that. E.g. `ocsetup TelnetServer`.

So the question is how to list all not/installed optional component names on command line?

Comment: What is ***ocsetup*** tool ?

Answer (score 2):

The answer was found thanks to this [msdn blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gremlininthemachine/archive/2010/04/28/detecting-which-windows-optional-components-are-installed-in-a-machine.aspx).

Using powershell, list all installed optional components:

`$(foreach ($feature in Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OptionalFeature -Namespace root\CIMV2 -Filter "InstallState = 1") {$feature.Name}) | sort`

List all not installed optional components:

`$(foreach ($feature in Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OptionalFeature -Namespace root\CIMV2 -Filter "InstallState != 1") {$feature.Name}) | sort`

Comment: compare 2 windows servers (W2012 R2 and W2016) installed components ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DISM](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh824821.aspx) (Deployment Image Servicing and Management), e.g.

```
dism /Online /Get-Features /Format:Table
```

Check `dism /Online /?` for help.